# Scrape text value from website but getting AttributeError

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the text value "S&P 500 Index" from the bloomberg website but I am receiving the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tester.py", line 17, in 
>       name = name_box.text.strip()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

[image]

My Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

#query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
page = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND', verify=False)

#parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

#get the companyName
name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'companyName__99a4824b'})
name = name_box.text.strip()
print(name_box)

#get the index price
price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price__c3a38e1d'})
price = price_box.text
print(price)
```

Comment: First off, you should show the entire error message, this helps debugging. Likely `price_box` is `None` and you try to call its `.text`... Or `name_box` for that matter.

Comment: Running your code and saving it to and HTML file and then viewing it in the browser gives a heading that says `Terms of Service Violation`. The HTML is not as the same as the HTML you are viewing on the webpage in your browser, and thus bs4 cannot find the `h1` tag with the specified class

Comment: You are correct, the full error has been added.

Comment: Thanks @AaronGarton that makes sense. Is there any workaround other than using bs4 that you know?

Comment: You could try using `selenium`. It will simulate a real browsing experience for you, and will allow you to get the HTML content on the webpage you want, without receiving the violation error. Checkout https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/